# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory Error

Tags: java, maven, junit, apache-commons, castor

I am getting this error after upgrading my project to Java 8.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Commons-logging is definitely present in the classpath and there is no issue compiling the code. However, at runtime JVM is not able to locate LogFactory. The issue only comes into picture when I am running in Java 8. It works fine with all versions below Java 8. We are also using Maven 1.X in the project.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Your runtime environment is missing one or more jar files.  Verify that you have deployed all the necessary jar files, AND that they are the same versions as the jars used in the build environment.

Comment: This is happening while running Junit tests. All the necessary jars are in place. Once again, I don't face this issue with Java 7, it only happens with Java 8.

Comment: Although it reports a ClassNotFound it could be that the static initialization of the LogFactory fails. That would also lead to a CNF.